# Read PLC tag using OPC UA

Tags: c#, plc, opc-ua

I want to read tags from a C# console app (framework 4.7) on a Siemens S7-1200 PLC.

My code works when reading tags on WinCC OPC UA Server (Siemens's HMI system). NodeIDs have all the same pattern, like "ns=2;s=Barcode" or "ns=2;s=Motor1Alarm".

On the S7 PLC, it's different.
[image]

NodeID looks like "ns=5;i=8" for example. Even if I try this address, server returns a "BadSessionIDInvalid" exception. I tried "ns=2;s=ServerInterfaces/Test/DM_Barcode", but always the same exception.

can someone help me on this?
thanks a lot for your time and help

Comment: can you share the code how you are calling it? Ideally the most simpliest and reproducible example

Comment: Focus on what the error tells you. It complains about the session ID, not the node ID.  Trouble with the connection, not the node.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion. Error is "BadNodeIdException"